# Given a square matrix A, which inner products are invariant under ("conjugation" by) A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, hermitian-matrices

Let $M$ be a symmetric positive definite square matrix. Such a matrix defines an inner product.

Let $A$ be another square matrix. We define $B = A^t M A$.

Under which circumstances do we have $M = B$? In other words, under which conditions is the inner product defined by $M$ invariant under conjugatin by $A$?

A necessary condition is that $A$ is invertible. What else can be said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A^TMA=M
\Leftrightarrow
I=M^{-1/2}A^TMAM^{-1/2}=(M^{1/2}AM^{-1/2})^T(M^{1/2}AM^{-1/2}).
$$
This means that $M^{1/2}AM^{-1/2}$ is real orthogonal, i.e. $A=M^{-1/2}QM^{1/2}$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Comment: thank you pointing out that typo.